# Why does Visual Studio Code catch an exception in the very beginning of my main?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, gdb

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.33.0 with a custom build arm-linux-gnueabi linaro c++ cross-compiler for the rpi3 based on the gcc 7.3.1. I am debugging the remotely attached rpi3 with gdbserver. I use opencv and pipe a X11 window through ssh.

I am on Mac OS 10.14.4

Visual Studio Code pauses debugging right here:[image: Exception has occured]

After pressing f5 or continue again it opens the X11 Window and everything works fine. So it doesn't crash nor quits.

Has someone experienced this behavior before?

EDIT4:

I think this is tied to the following problem:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/763#issuecomment-305001194

EDIT3:

Exception is not caused by piping through the window.

EDIT2:

This works without an exception on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 Community, same setup, same project, same compiler (linaro 7.3.1) and VisualGDB

EDIT:
This is what the Callstack looks like. I am not executing any code before main. There are just some global static constexpr.

[image: Callstack and variables]

Answer (score 2):

*Update*: As @rustyx noted in the comments, the sort of problem I describe here probably would not produce the symptom in the OP because the program does continue. Most likely it is a problem in the toolchain / inter-device debugging.

I'd suggest trying GDB by itself and see if you get the same results or more info.

---

This can happen if you have initialized some global or static variable before `main()`, and that initialization causes an exception. See Matt Godbolt's talk at CppCon 2018 "[The Bits Between the Bits: How We Get to main()](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOfucXtyEsU)".

Consider this:

```cpp
int main() {}

// Initialized before main
static const auto x = []( auto i ) { if( i == 0 ) throw; return i; }( 0 );
```

Comment: I will check the talk thanks! This is a big project and it is possible that there are some global statics somewhere. I will find them eliminate them and confirm this!

Comment: But then the program would terminate and main() would never be executed.

Comment: I don't have any code which is excecuted before main. I have some gobal static constexpr variables which are filled by macros but nothing like your example.

Comment: @rustyx: You may be right, but I'm not sure how gdb/vscode would behave in the scenario described. It could be a bug in the toolchain, which is itself a little atypical.

Comment: I have the same toolchain running on windows with Visual Studio 2017 and the same project and it works without that exception why atypical? :)

Comment: I just mean that remote debugging RPi (esp. on Mac) is a relatively rare use case compared to local debugging or iOS debugging.